# Python + setuptools: distributing a pre-compiled shared library with boost.python bindings

Tags: python, c++, boost, setuptools

I have a C++ library (we'll call it Example in the following) for which I wrote Python bindings using the boost.python library. This Python-wrapped library will be called pyExample. The entire project is built using CMake and the resulting Python-wrapped library is a file named `libpyExample.so`.

When I use the Python bindings from a Python script located in the same directory as `libpyExample.so`, I simply have to write:

```
import libpyExample
libpyExample.hello_world()
```

and this executes a `hello_world()` function exposed by the wrapping process.

## What I want to do

For convenience, I would like my pyExample library to be available from anywhere simply using the command

```
import pyExample
```

I also want pyExample to be easily installable in any virtualenv in just one command. So I thought a convenient process would be to use setuptools to make that happen. That would therefore imply:

- Making `libpyExample.so` visible for any Python script
- Changing the name under which the module is accessed

I did find many things about compiling C++ extensions with setuptools, but nothing about packaging a pre-compiled C++ extension. Is what I want to do even possible?

## What I do not want to do

I don't want to build the pyExample library with setuptools, I would like to avoid modifying the existing project too much. The CMake build is just fine, I can retrieve the `libpyExample.so` file very easily.

Comment: The proper approach is to compile as part of the setup process. If it's C++ code, I would doubly recommend recompiling.

Comment: I know that, but the library is not cross-platform and it is really complicated to change the build system. I found a dirty workaround while going through the [setuptools documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html). I just (1) created a `pyExample` directory containing the init script for namespace renaming, (2) registered my `libpyExample.so` file as a package data file (it was not recognized as a package file, I don't know why) and (3) made sure that the `zip_safe` argument was set to `False` when calling the `setup` function. Now, `setup.py` works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have the following situation:

- you have an existing CMake-based build of a C++ library with Python bindings
- you want to package this library with setuptools

The latter then allows you to call `python setup.py install --user`, which installs the lib in the `site-packages` directory and makes it available from every path in your system.

What you want is possible, if you overload the classes that setuptools uses to build extensions, so that those classes actually call your CMake build system. This is not trivial, but you can find a working example here, provided by the pybind11 project:

https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example

Have a look into `setup.py`, you will see how the classes `build_ext` and `Extension` are inherited from and modified to execute the CMake build.

This should work out of the box for you or with little modification - if your build requires special `-D` flags to be set.
I hope this helps!

Comment: This does not exactly answer the original question and is actually following the logic of the comment by @Petesh. However, with experience (I asked this question 2+ years ago), I think it's indeed quite feasible, especially now that pybind11 makes things so easy.

Comment: If the original question was not correctly answered, you could let me know what I misunderstood, then I can improve the answer. @Petesh did not give any details of how to achieve any of this.

Comment: The goal I had in mind when I posted this question was to compile the C++ library manually (i.e. by calling CMake and Make from a terminal), copy the resulting `.so` file "manually" to an appropriate location in the Python package file tree and use the setup script to install it to the Python file tree. What you propose in your answer is more elegant, it doesn't require to modify the build process and it is conveniently achievable with pybind11. I think it solves the problem I had back then (reason why I accepted the answer).

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Sorry that my answer came too late for your original problem, and thank you for accepting the answer anyway :)